# Counting SQLite rows that might match multiple times in a single query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table which has a column containing categories that each row may fall into. Each row has a unique ID, but may fall into zero, one, or more categories, for example:

```
|-------+-------|
| name  | cats  |
|-------+-------|
| xyzzy | a b c |
| plugh | b     |
| quux  |       |
| quuux | a c   |
|-------+-------|
```

I'd like to obtain counts of how many items are in each category. In other words, output like this:

```
|------------+-------|
| categories | total |
|------------+-------|
| a          | 2     |
| b          | 2     |
| c          | 2     |
| none       | 1     |
|------------+-------|
```

I tried to use the `case` statement like this:

```
select case
    when cats like "%a%" then 'a'
    when cats like "%b%" then 'b'
    when cats like "%c%" then 'c'
    else 'none'
end as categories,
count(*)
from test
group by categories
```

But the problem is this only counts each row *once*, so it can't handle multiple categories. You then get this output instead:

```
|------------+-------|
| categories | total |
|------------+-------|
| a          | 2     |
| b          | 1     |
| none       | 1     |
|------------+-------|
```

One possibility is to use as many `union` statements as you have categories:

```
select case
    when cats like "%a%" then 'a'
end as categories, count(*)
from test
group by categories
union
select case
    when cats like "%b%" then 'b'
end as categories, count(*)
from test
group by categories
union
...
```

but this seems really ugly and the opposite of DRY.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your data structure!  You should have a table with one row per `name` and per `category`:

```
create table nameCategories (
    name varchar(255),
    category varchar(255)
);
```

Then your query would be easy:

```
select category, count(*)
from namecategories
group by category;
```

Why is your data structure bad?  Here are some reasons:

- A column should contain a single value.
- SQL has pretty lousy string functionality.
- SQL queries to do what you want cannot be optimized.
- SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table*, not a *string*.

With that in mind, here is one brute force method for doing what you want:

```
with categories as (
      select 'a' as category union all
      select 'b' union all
      . . .
     )
select c.category, count(t.category)
from categories c left join
     test t
     on ' ' || t.categories || ' ' like '% ' || c.category || ' %' 
group by c.category;
```

If you already have a table of valid categories, then the CTE is not needed.

Comment: Thanks! Agreed that's how it *should* be, but we don't always get to choose the data sets we work with :)

Can you explain what's happening in the left join? I'm trying to follow why that works and haven't seen the syntax you're using in the on part.

Comment: @KyleBarbour . . . The `LEFT JOIN` simply keeps all the categories in your list, even if there are not matches in `test`.